# Hibernate join one to many by java

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate and I have two tables:

```
Table A:
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {
 
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
 private List<Book>book;
}
```

and

```
Table B
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book extends BaseEntity {
   
    @Column(name = "nameOfBook")
    private String nameOfBook;

    @Column(name = "userId")
    private String userId;


}
```

I have to do the following query:

```
select *
from users, books
where books.nameOfBook == 'duck' and users.id == books.userId
```

My problem that I have not understood how to convert the SQL in Java like this:

```
  Subquery<String>query = query.subquery(String.class);
            Root<Supplier> psFrom = supplierQuery.from(User.class);
            Path<String> expression = psFrom.get("id");
            supplierQuery.select(expression);
```

Comment: What is the relation between `books` and `users`? I think you are getting results in Cartesian product

Comment: An users read one or more books

Comment: How are you storing your data with relation in your database?